# Efficient way of retrieving text from page

Tags: perl, web-scraping

I have the following command in Perl that iterates through a lot of variables and pulls a certain value/number from each page. If the value is invalid, it returns "Error"

```
my $output = `curl -s -H "Cookie: $cookie_name=$target" -L "$site"$target | grep -Eo "You have <strong>[0-9]+" | grep -Eo "[0-9]+"` || "Error\n";
```

Here is an example of the page contents.

`... You have <strong>1829</strong> reports ...`

All I want to return is the `1829` for example.

Is there a more efficient way to pull this data?

Comment: Why is this not efficient?

Comment: I am running grep twice to filter the text. Would it be better to just use regex to pull the info from $output?

Comment: Grep is really fast. Does your code feel slow? Does the 2ms difference matter? Sure, there are different ways to do this, but your current solution is not in any way inefficient.

Comment: Well I am getting a lot of "Error"s when there shouldnt be but I cannot be certain if thats because of the curl command

Comment: Microoptimization. Running `curl` and pulling text over the network is orders of magnitude slower than any extraction program.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: You probably want to use an actual HTML parser to find the data.  How do you know that there will only be one `<strong>(digits)</strong>` on the page?  Or that it won't look like `<strong class="emphasis">  1829 </strong>` and foil your regexes?  Look at http://htmlparsing.com/regexes for more examples of why regexes are a fragile solution to extracting data from HTML.

Comment: The 'errors' i get just display my "Error" because of the end of the code that has `|| "Error"`.
I know for a fact there will only be one instance because that is how the website is designed

Comment: @Bijan That just means that the output of the commands in backticks is empty. This could be because `curl` fails to download a particular page, but it's just as likely because `grep` doesn't find any matches. And that is one reason that you should generally avoid using `system` and backticks: error checking is a pain.

Answer (score 3):

This is not significantly more efficient, it might even be slightly more inefficient, but an alternate approach that doesn't involve shelling out is :

```
use v5.14;
use LWP::Simple;

my $content= get($url) // die "Couldn't get content";
if ($content =~ m/You have <strong>([0-9]+)/) {
    print "reports = $1";
} else {
    die "Can't parse the page?";
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot use LWP because I need to pass in a specific value for the cookie.

Comment: You can pass in cookies with LWP.  You can pass in any header you want with LWP.